# Problem in Comparing Start date and End date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, date-format

If I used date format 'MM/yyyy' like this, then it will work properly, but I wanted to use date format like this 'm/YYYY'. How to compare it?

Below code is working properly, but I wanted to use date format 'm/yyyy' like this.

```
$('#card_form_plan_start_date').datepicker({
  format: 'MM/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  viewMode: 'months', 
  minViewMode: 'months'
});

$('#card_form_plan_start_date').datepicker().on(
      'change',
      function() {
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').val('');
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').datepicker("destroy");
        var newStart = new Date($(this).val());
alert($(this).val());        
newStart.setDate(newStart.getDate());

        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').datepicker({
            startDate : newStart,
            format: 'MM/yyyy',
              autoclose: true,
              viewMode: 'months', 
              minViewMode: 'months'
        });
});
```

End month starts from start month, if I use date format like this 'MM/YYYY', how to do it with 'm/YYYY'?

Comment: use 'M/yyyy' instead of 'm/YYYY' it will works

Comment: No brother. I want a month in number format

Comment: do you want result like this '2/2019' and are you using bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Yeah. Working properly only if I use date format like this 'MM/yyyy', but i want date in number format

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: check this link https://jsfiddle.net/0h1x3j7d/

Comment: I want two datepickers, end date month should start from start date month, and format should be m/yyyy. ie. 04/2019

Comment: can you add some more html code to solve your problem

Comment: <input type="text" id="card_form_plan_start_date" class="form-control timepicker" name="card_form_plan_start_date">     <input type="text" id="card_form_plan_end_date" class="form-control timepicker" name="card_form_plan_end_date">

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `var newStart = new Date($(this).val());`
try to use the below code in your js

```
var comDate = $(this).val().split('/'); 
var newStart = new Date(comDate[1], comDate[0], 1);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#card_form_plan_start_date').datepicker({
  format: 'm/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  viewMode: 'months', 
  minViewMode: 'months'
});

$('#card_form_plan_start_date').datepicker().on(
      'change',
      function() {
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').val('');
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').datepicker("destroy");
        //var newStart = new Date($(this).val());  
        //newStart.setDate(newStart.getMonth());
        var comDate = $(this).val().split('/'); 
        var newStart = new Date(comDate[1], comDate[0], 1);
        $('#card_form_plan_end_date').datepicker({
            startDate : newStart,
            format: 'm/yyyy',
              autoclose: true,
              viewMode: 'months', 
              minViewMode: 'months'
        });
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
 

    <div class="row">
   
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" id="card_form_plan_start_date" class="form-control timepicker" name="card_form_plan_start_date"> <input type="text" id="card_form_plan_end_date" class="form-control timepicker" name="card_form_plan_end_date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```